# Why don't teach the infinite sum approach of Lebesgue integral?

Tags: measure-theory, education

The most intuitive way of teaching the two integration to kids is to use the following diagram:
[image]

For Riemann integration, the diagram directly translates to: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)(x_{i+1}-x_{i})$ and we use this to teach the K-12 kids all the time. It is quite useful.

Let $y=f(x)$

Why don't we use the similar formula to teach the Lebesgue integration:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \mu(y>y_{i})(y_{i+1}-y_i)?$$

I've never seen this infinite sum anywhere. All texts use some $f_n$ and take the limit.

Comment: This question belongs in https://matheducators.stackexchange.com

Comment: The "horizontal slice" method IS what we use, though! The [simple functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function) are finite sums of horizontal bars. Then as we let the simple function approximations become more complicated we approach the actual integral. Usually we phrase this as the limit over all approximations, because this is formally nice, but I don't immediately see a reason you couldn't take a particular sequence of progressively better approximations, indicated by a sum over more and more parts, and then take the limit (as you want to do).

Comment: What you are describing is in essence integrating $f\geq 0$ by approximating it by simple functions $s_n(t)=\sum^{2^nn-1}_{k=0}\frac{k}{2^n}\mathbb{1}_{[2^{-n}k,2^{-n}(k+1))}(f(x))$, which is commonly covered in courses and books on Lebesgue integration.

Comment: Perhaps linked: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549226/why-is-the-undergraph-definition-of-lebesgue-integral-so-rare?rq=1